# Trying to get a random temperature from a range of possible temperatures for a city

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python. I'm trying to use this function to get a random possible temperature from a list of cities.
Here's my code so far. I kepe getting this traceback error. "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"
What could I try to get the function to return a random value from the range.

```
import random

def get_temperature(city_name: str) -> int:
    """Gets a random temperature from a possible range for a city."""
    temperature = ""
    if city_name == "Pocatello":
        return temperature in random.randrange(1600, 8790)
    elif city_name == "Orlando":
        return temperature in random.randrange(5000, 9150)
    elif city_name == "Salt Lake City":
        return temperature in random.randrange(2600, 8990)
    elif city_name == "Dallas":
        return temperature in random.randrange(3000, 9490)
    elif city_name == "Ann Arbor":
        return temperature in random.randrange(1800, 8290)
    elif city_name == "Phoenix":
        return temperature in random.randrange(4600, 10590)
    elif city_name == "Anchorage":
        return temperature in random.randrange(1100, 6490)
    elif city_name == "Honolulu":
        return temperature in random.randrange(8790, 6600)
    elif city_name == "Cloud City":  # for fun
        return temperature in random.randrange(6000, 7000)
    else:
        return temperature in random.randrange(1100, 10590)

print(get_temperature("Dallas"))
```

Comment: I think that in each case you meant something like this: `return random.randrange(1600, 8790)`. Your `temperature` variable seems redundant.

Comment: Thank you so much! That seemed to fix it :D

Comment: or also possible: a series `temperature = random.randrange(6000, 7000)` after each if/elif/else, and `return temperature` at the end.

Comment: Why not have a dictionary keyed by the cities and whose values are the limits that you are choosing from? You could replace that tedious `if ... elif` cascade by just 1 or 2  lines of code.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks. This was just practice for getting comfortable with if statements. Ty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return temperature in random.randrange(x,y)` is incorrect - that's invalid code because not only is temperature an empty string & will never exist in the output from the `randrange` function, but also the variable is redundant.

Also, this is a great textbook example of where to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) - you could reduce this function massively by having the city names as keys & the ranges as values.

You would also be benefiting from a lookup performance improvement as the [avg. time complexity for a dict get item operation is constant](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#dict) - `O(n)`.

However, try this instead:

```py
import random

def get_temperature(city_name: str) -> int:
    """Gets a random temperature from a possible range for a city."""
    if city_name == "Pocatello":
        return random.randrange(1600, 8790)
    elif city_name == "Orlando":
        return random.randrange(5000, 9150)
    elif city_name == "Salt Lake City":
        return random.randrange(2600, 8990)
    elif city_name == "Dallas":
        return random.randrange(3000, 9490)
    elif city_name == "Ann Arbor":
        return random.randrange(1800, 8290)
    elif city_name == "Phoenix":
        return random.randrange(4600, 10590)
    elif city_name == "Anchorage":
        return random.randrange(1100, 6490)
    elif city_name == "Honolulu":
        return random.randrange(8790, 6600)
    elif city_name == "Cloud City":  # for fun
        return random.randrange(6000, 7000)
    else:
        return random.randrange(1100, 10590)

print(get_temperature("Dallas"))
```